# How do I purge my revoked GPG key from existence?

Tags: git, github, gnupg

**Back Story:**

I've recently started learning about Linux and in parallel doing a few online courses and keeping tack of my practice code in a private repo in github as personal notes.
I've started learning about GPG keys recently in the process. I clearly do not have enough knowledge on them.

1. Created a github account with an email.
   Example original email is `something@gmail.com` - I used `something+github@gmail.com` for maintaining few filters in my email account.
2. Created a repo on github with license and readme files.
3. Added security so that my primary email cannot be used to commit the work. I want to use the github provided no-reply email for generating the GPG keys and use them to verify and sign my commits.
4. I made mistakes and created gpg key with my primary email. I set up git to have `user.email` in config to have no-reply email.
5. I found the issue after few commits as they are all unverified.
6. I revoked the GPG key generated. Deleted the public key associated with this gpg key from github account.
7. I have created an entirely new GPG key with the no-reply github email and using it for signing the further commits in that repo.

**Actual Question:**

What does revocation actually do? Does it temporarily make this key unusable or permanently unusable? I wish for the latter.

If it is needed, I want to purge this GPG key out from existence everywhere so that I can completely forget about it.

Is there anything more I should do apart from this revocation? It would be helpful if I were to be provided the commands for it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply a revocation to a GPG key this key is permanently retired, and cannot be undone.

I will attache some documentation that will be helpful for you, also this question had been answered, I will give you the link to that too.

But I will give you some commands: (they will be found in the documentation)

*List keys*

```
gpg --list-keys
```

*Revoke your key*

```
gpg --output revoke.asc --gen-revoke key-ID
```

*Import revocation certificate into your keyring*

```
gpg --import revoke.asc
```

*Search your key on the key-server*

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --search-keys key-ID
```

*Send the revoked key to the key-server*

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --send-keys key-ID
```

***Just to be clear***

Here is the documentation and the link of the commands I Just give you:

[GIT](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1099), [Documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1099), [Git Documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1099), [The Response](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1099)

Comment: I did all those steps before even posting the question but was in a doubt if revocation of the GPG key enough to permanently retire it. But your answer has cleared me of the doubt.